# How to properly configure GitBook Space's README.md?

Tags: gitbook

I'm using GitBook's GitLab integration to create a documentation for a product my company is preparing to launch. The below is how the git-sync'd Space currently looks like from app.gitbook.com:

[image]

Currently, I have the following files in my project root:

```
usage-doc/
|
+-- README.md
+-- SUMMARY.md
+-- book.json
```

`book.json` has the following:

```json
{
  "title": "Usage Documentation",
  "description": "Hello World"
}
```

The problems I'd like to solve are the following:

1. From the [gitbook docs](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/master/docs/config.md#general-settings): `Title of your book, default value is extracted from the README. On legacy.gitbook.com this field is pre-filled.` However neither the title I added inside of `README.md`, nor the `"title"` key I had set in `book.json` seem to be correctly extracted for display on the GitBook space, which you can see still show up as "**Untitled**" on the sidebar, and the README page displays the generic "**README**" text, while the title "___ Usage Documentation" shows up as a description underneath.
2. I'd like to add another section link/shortcut on the README page, below "Seller" for "Buyer". How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The features you are referring to, are about GitBook Legacy which is a version GitBook hasn't been supporting for years. GitBook is a cloud offering now, and the official docs are here: https://docs.gitbook.com.

The way to change the title of the space itself in your example is to type the title at the top where it says: "Enter a title for this space". Then let it sync. Git sync is a two way sync. When you change something in the GitBook Space, it syncs to the Git repository, and vice versa.

> I'd like to add another section link/shortcut on the README page, below "Seller" for "Buyer". How would I do that?

Here's an example `SUMMARY.md` file that shows pages, a group and a link:

```
# Table of contents

* [README](README.md)
* [Test](test.md)

## Group

* [Group](group/group.md)

***

* [My blog](https://petros.blog)
```

The way to add pages, groups, or links from within the space itself is via a change request. That is, you need to click Edit to start a new change request. After doing so, you will see a New page option in the left sidebar. If you click the option you can choose what you want to add.